# Data table - Quick view vs opening subpage (displaying details of the item)

Tags: tables, data-tables

I have a table filled with data. There is possibility to see more details for each item (row), it can be done in two ways

- user can open subpage for each item
- or open a quick view window

**Quick window** works for multiple items at the same same time (but shows limited information), is related to the selection, all the selected items are also displayed in quick window.

**Subpage** displays details just for one item at the time (but contains full information).

[image: 2 different ways of displaying item details]

**I have a problem with creating proper way of opening item details - how to make it clear that there are 2 possibilities - quick window or supage? I'm not able to predict which way will be used more. Maybe there is another way you are familiar with and could share with me?**

So far I came up with 3 ideas, but neither is 100% satisfying IMO.

1st flow (image below): Adding icon "open in new"

- Quick View opens by clicking the item
- Subpage opens by clicking the icon

[image: 1st flow]

2nd flow (image below):

- Quick View opens by clicking selection
- Subpage opens by clicking the item

[image: 2nd flow]

3rd flow (image below):

- Quick View opens by clicking item
- Supbage opens by clicking item but by using Quick Window

This solution requires 2 click to go straight to the Details Subpage, so I believe its the worst

[image: 3rd flow]

Comment: I disagree, I think the 3rd is the best because it doesn't confuse people with multple options/paths. In this case a second click to get to more information is not per-see a bad thing. But this might be a misperception, maybe people will know where/what to click and get exactly what they expect. It would help if you can provide more context so answers won't have to be based on such assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reading your options this is what I went with in my head:

1st flow (image below): Adding icon "open in new"
Quick View opens by clicking the item
Subpage opens by clicking the icon

The fact that you have the "quick view" should mean that it will be used more often than the subpage thus should be accessible via the simplest action - click. Otherwise there is no point for it and just use the subpage only.

You can just implement this way and add some anchors to count the actual uses of both actions. See how many users actually open the quick view and how long they stay there (measure time between that click and the next one on some other action) versus opening of the full page.

You can also use A/B testing if you have the capabilities in your feature flag system and see which way is better for the users.